# is there a way to share react page on Facebook and pass an image?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, twitter, react-share

am trying to make my react page shareable on Facebook and Twitter.
I tried everything I could, I have been googling all day, but I cant find the  answer.

```
 <FacebookShareButton url={window.location.href} title={exactNews.text ?exactNews.title : ""}> 
      <FaFacebookF/>
 </FacebookShareButton>
```

any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass an image to the share options anymore, the only way to add an image to a shared URL is by using the `og:image` tag in the source. Be aware that Facebook ignores JavaScript, so the `og:image` tag must be in the original source and not dynamically added via JavaScript. Facebook then automatically uses the image specified in the `og:image` tag.

More information: https://ogp.me/

You can use https://prerender.io/benefits/social-media-sharing/ or a framework like Next.js to render pages server side, with the correct OG images.

Comment: yeah, I have been trying to do that with dynamical method but I guess there is no way. how can I make it work? for now am trying to make it work using react-helmet-async, but I dont think that it will work. I cant just add it statically, because am fetching images from api. any tips on how to make it work?

Comment: you really have to generate the og tags serverside, there is no way around that...

Comment: willl pre-render help my case?

Comment: i dont know your code, but as long as the source includes the og tags without any javascript, it is fine

Comment: @YUKIMURA I've been trying for days to find a solution, were you able to resolve this? if yes how?

Comment: @RubenMartins you can try this, for example: https://prerender.io/benefits/social-media-sharing/

Comment: @RubenMartins as far as am concerned, you cant do that with only react, I solved it using next.js.